# C# dapper map to interface

Tags: c#, dapper

Can i use C# dapper to do something like this:

```
IFoo bar = _dbConnection.Query<IFoo>("My query there");
```

Now I can't do it, due to not impelemented default parameterless constructor.

Is there some trick to honor gods of SOLID (especially spirits of Liskov Substitution Principle) or should i leave it as it is and map my data not to IFoo but to Foo?

I'm really worrying about respecting these SOLID stuff, but still don't know where i should do it, so looking for an advice for this concrete situation.

Comment: Mapping to an interface doesn't really make sense. How is Dapper supposed to know what type to use?

Comment: The variable can be `IFoo` but you have to tell Dapper what the concrete type is.

Comment: I don' t know dapper. But it would absolutely make sense. When you would query for an interface in NHibernate, it queries all the mapped entities which implement that interface. Additionally it is possible to map interfaces, for instance like a base class.

Comment: Dapper doesn't automagically currently scan for concrete implementations of abstract types; however, if you *want that*, there is something you can do with `GetRowParser<T>` (from an `IDataReader`) that does something very similar - but you'd still need to tell it the concrete type manually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a concrete implementation of your class to instantiate. Internally, it has to do a create a new object. You can't create a new instance of an interface:

```
var foo = new IFoo(); // This won't build!
```

You can still cast your **result** to an interface, but you need a concrete type to build from the database.

```
IEnumerable<IFoo> foo = _dbConnection.Query<Foo>("My query there");
```

Comment: For the record: I can show examples where "This won't build!": *will* (still with `IFoo` as an interface). But, in essence: yeah, this is about right. `Query<T>` actually returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, but that's a small point.

Answer (score 1):

One way to organise repository is to use private class objects for querying, but expose results as public interfaces.

Pulbic Model:

```
namespace MyProject.Foo.Model
{
    public interface IFoo
    {
        string Property1 { get; set; }
        string Property2 { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IFooRepository
    {
        IEnumerbale<IFoo> GetFoos();
    }
}
```

Query implementation with private class:

```
namespace MyProject.Foo.Repositories
{
    public class FooRepository: IFooRepository
    {
        private class Foo: IFoo
        {
            public string Property1 { get; set; }
            public string Property2 { get; set; }
        }

        public IEnumerbale<IFoo> GetFoos()
        {
            IEnumerable<IFoo> foo = _dbConnection.Query<Foo>("My query there");
            return foo;
        }
    }
}
```